Getting "Signature for this request is not valid." in Binance websocket api while using ed25519 keys in C++
Hi I'm trying to send orders to Binance websocket api wss://ws-api.binance.com:443/ws-api/v3. I'm using ed25519 keys to sign my order json data. When i'm sending the request i'm getting:
{"id":"my_new_order","status":400,"error":{"code":-1022,"msg":"Signature for this request is not valid."},"rateLimits":[{"rateLimitType":"REQUEST_WEIGHT","interval":"MINUTE","intervalNum":1,"limit":6000,"count":3}]}
I have even tried sorting the json parameters alphabetically , but it still did not work.
But i tried with the example python code given in their docs and it worked.
I'm using sodium library to generate signatures.
std::string privateKeyData = "MY_PRIVATE_KEY";
    if (privateKeyData.empty()) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Set up the request parameters
    std::string symbol = "BTCUSDT";
    std::string side = "BUY";
    std::string type = "LIMIT";
    std::string timeInForce = "IOC";
    std::string quantity = "0.001";
    std::string price = "50000";

    // Timestamp the request
    std::string timestampStr = timestamp();

    // Construct the message to sign
    std::string message = "apiKey=" + API_KEY + "&symbol=" + symbol +
        "&side=" + side + "&type=" + type + "&timeInForce=" + timeInForce +
        "&quantity=" + quantity + "&price=" + price + "&timestamp=" + timestampStr;

    // Load the private key for signing
    unsigned char privateKey[crypto_sign_ed25519_SECRETKEYBYTES];
    if (crypto_sign_ed25519_sk_to_pk(privateKey, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(privateKeyData.data())) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Failed to load private key." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Sign the message
    unsigned char signature[crypto_sign_BYTES];
    unsigned long long signatureLength;
    if (crypto_sign_detached(signature, &signatureLength,
                             reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(message.data()), message.size(),
                             privateKey) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Failed to sign message." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Encode the signature as base64
    char encodedSignature[crypto_sign_BYTES * 2 + 1];
    if (sodium_bin2base64(encodedSignature, sizeof(encodedSignature), signature, signatureLength, sodium_base64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL) == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Failed to encode signature." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Add the signature to the request parameters
    std::cout << "Signature: " << encodedSignature << std::endl;


    std::string base64Signature(encodedSignature);

    // Construct the JSON string manually
    std::string jsonRequest = "{"
        "\"id\": \"my_new_order\","
        "\"method\": \"order.place\","
        "\"params\": {"
        "\"apiKey\": \"" + API_KEY + "\","
        "\"price\": \"" + price + "\","
        "\"quantity\": \"" + quantity + "\","
        "\"side\": \"" + side + "\","
        "\"symbol\": \"" + symbol + "\","
        "\"timeInForce\": \"" + timeInForce + "\","
        "\"timestamp\": " + timestampStr + ","
        "\"type\": \"" + type + "\","
        "\"signature\": \"" + base64Signature + "\""
        "}"
        "}";

    // Print the JSON string
    std::cout << "JSON Request:\n" << jsonRequest << std::endl;

The JSON request formed looks like :
{"id": "my_new_order","method": "order.place","params": {"apiKey": "MY_API_KEY","price": "50000","quantity": "0.001","side": "BUY","symbol": "BTCUSDT","timeInForce": "IOC","timestamp": 1713859232000,"type": "LIMIT","signature": "GENERATED_SIGNATURE"}}

to this i got the response mentioned above.
For comparison the python request payload looks like:
{'id': 'my_new_order', 'method': 'order.place', 'params': {'apiKey': 'MY_API_KEY','price': '50000', 'quantity': '0.001', 'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'side': 'BUY', 'timeInForce': 'IOC', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'timestamp': 1713859985702, 'signature': 'GENERATED_SIGNATURE'}}

Any solution other than using sodium is also welcomed.

This is not a [mre]. You left out several constants and we have no idea what the expected outcome is, given that we do not have access to your private key.

In the C code the timestamp() function is missing. Check whether it returns the Unix timestamp in milliseconds (!), possibly the timestamp is validated. Also: Ed25519 is deterministic. Provisionally use the same timestamp in both codes and compare the signatures obtained with the Python and C code.

@Topaco i hardcoded the message to sign in both the versions and found that the signature generated is different between C++ and python, but is same during multiple generation in their own versions.

If the Ed25519 signatures are different for identical message and key, you have a signing issue, which you should solve first. Post sample data (message, key, signature) and the C code (for the latter, post only the relevant part: passing your test data to crypto_sign_detached(), Base64 encoding of the signature with sodium_bin2base64() and output of the Base64 encoded signature).

Note: the Python example expects a 32-byte private key, whereas libsodium expects a 32-byte seed and a 32-byte public key. I am not sure whether you can trivially convert one into the other.

The C code essentially has two bugs:

In the Python reference code, the signature is generated from the alphabetically ordered parameters, which have the following order:
payload apiKey=...&price=...&quantity=...&side=...&symbol=...&timeInForce=...&timestamp=...&type=...

In the C code, a different order is applied. This must be changed so that it corresponds to the order in the Python code.

Python and C code use different key conventions. In the C code, the typical Libsodium convention is used, in which the secret key (64 bytes) is a concatenation of the seed (32 bytes) and the public key (32 bytes), s. here, while in the Python code the seed is referred to as the private key and is used alone, s. here. In principle, the seed is sufficient, as the public key can be derived from the seed, but the Libsodium convention is more performant, as this derivation can be omitted during signing.
As Botje already noted in their comment, in the C code only the seed is used. This is wrong and behaves during signing as if an incorrect/inconsistent public key is applied. An incorrect public key is in turn reflected in a correct r and an incorrect s (keep in mind that the Ed25519 signature consists of two parts, r (32 bytes) and s (32 bytes), which are concatenated. While in r only the private key is involved, in s the public key is also involved).
However, this characteristic behavior is not observable due to the first bug, which results in a generally different signature (i.e. also an incorrect r).
The fix here is that the secret key must be used instead of the seed when signing. Libsodium provides the crypto_sign_seed_keypair() function for deriving the secret and public key from the seed.


C code (for the sake of simplicity without error handling):
// "seed" is called "privateKey" in the Python wrapper/port
unsigned char seed[32] =
{
    0x80, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x85, 0x86, 0x87, 0x88, 0x89, 0x8a, 0x8b, 0x8c, 0x8d, 0x8e, 0x8f,
    0x90, 0x91, 0x92, 0x93, 0x94, 0x95, 0x96, 0x97, 0x98, 0x99, 0x9a, 0x9b, 0x9c, 0x9d, 0x9e, 0x9f
};

// Derive the secret key (sk)
unsigned char pk[crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
unsigned char sk[crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES];
crypto_sign_seed_keypair(pk, sk, seed);

// Set up the request parameters
std::string symbol = "BTCUSDT";
std::string side = "BUY";
std::string type = "LIMIT";
std::string timeInForce = "IOC";
std::string quantity = "0.001";
std::string price = "50000";

// Timestamp the request
std::string timestampStr = "1713978544129"; // timestamp(); // use a fixed timestamp for testing!
std::string API_KEY = "put your own API Key here";

// Fix 1: Use an alphabetical order (see sorted() in Python) 
std::string message = "apiKey=" + API_KEY + "&price=" + price + "&quantity=" + quantity + 
    "&side=" + side + "&symbol=" + symbol + "&timeInForce=" + timeInForce + 
    "&timestamp=" + timestampStr + "&type=" + type;

// Sign the alphabetical ordered data
unsigned char signature[crypto_sign_BYTES];
unsigned long long signatureLength;
char encodedSignature[sodium_base64_ENCODED_LEN(crypto_sign_BYTES, sodium_base64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL)];
crypto_sign_detached(signature, &signatureLength, (unsigned char*)message.data(), message.size(), sk); // Fix 2: Apply the secret key 
sodium_bin2base64(encodedSignature, sizeof(encodedSignature), signature, signatureLength, sodium_base64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL);

// Construct the JSON string manually (using Python formatting and ordering for easier comparison)
std::string jsonRequest = "{"
    "\"id\": \"my_new_order\", "
    "\"method\": \"order.place\", "
    "\"params\": {"
    "\"apiKey\": \"" + API_KEY + "\", "
    "\"symbol\": \"" + symbol + "\", "
    "\"side\": \"" + side + "\", "
    "\"type\": \"" + type + "\", "
    "\"timeInForce\": \"" + timeInForce + "\", "
    "\"quantity\": \"" + quantity + "\", "
    "\"price\": \"" + price + "\", "
    "\"timestamp\": " + timestampStr + ", "
    "\"signature\": \"" + encodedSignature + "\""
    "}"
    "}";

// Print the JSON string
std::cout << "JSON Request:\n" << jsonRequest << std::endl; // JSON Request: {"id": "my_new_order", "method" : "order.place", "params" : {"apiKey": "put your own API Key here", "symbol" : "BTCUSDT", "side" : "BUY", "type" : "LIMIT", "timeInForce" : "IOC", "quantity" : "0.001", "price" : "50000", "timestamp" : 1713978544129, "signature" : "7Rh8bRx0/VT8riNSC2POpR1+8p0gjXhL7mkOL/nfmhFQ6QbGCXRE6PZQ2cq+c6ZNPBXPc52jOIJ2bId6YbyIBw=="}}


Python reference code (from here):
import base64
import json
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ed25519 import Ed25519PrivateKey

# Set up authentication
API_KEY='put your own API Key here'

# Load the private key.
# In this example the key is expected to be stored without encryption,
# but we recommend using a strong password for improved security.
private_key = Ed25519PrivateKey.from_private_bytes(bytes.fromhex("808182838485868788898a8b8c8d8e8f909192939495969798999a9b9c9d9e9f"));
# alternatively, the key can be imported as PEM:
#data = b"""-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
#MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEIICBgoOEhYaHiImKi4yNjo+QkZKTlJWWl5iZmpucnZ6f
#-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"""
#private_key = load_pem_private_key(data, password=None)

# Set up the request parameters
params = {
    'apiKey':        API_KEY,
    'symbol':       'BTCUSDT',
    'side':         'BUY',
    'type':         'LIMIT',
    'timeInForce':  'IOC',
    'quantity':     '0.001',
    'price':        '50000'
}

# Timestamp the request
#timestamp = int(time.time() * 1000) # UNIX timestamp in milliseconds
timestamp = 1713978544129 # use a fixed timestamp for testing!
params['timestamp'] = timestamp

# Sign the request
payload = '&'.join([f'{param}={value}' for param, value in sorted(params.items())])

signature = base64.b64encode(private_key.sign(payload.encode('ASCII')))
params['signature'] = signature.decode('ASCII')

# Send the request
request = {
    'id': 'my_new_order',
    'method': 'order.place',
    'params': params
}

print(json.dumps(request)) # {"id": "my_new_order", "method": "order.place", "params": {"apiKey": "put your own API Key here", "symbol": "BTCUSDT", "side": "BUY", "type": "LIMIT", "timeInForce": "IOC", "quantity": "0.001", "price": "50000", "timestamp": 1713978544129, "signature": "7Rh8bRx0/VT8riNSC2POpR1+8p0gjXhL7mkOL/nfmhFQ6QbGCXRE6PZQ2cq+c6ZNPBXPc52jOIJ2bId6YbyIBw=="}}

